# Background DIV being cut off

Tags: html, css, background-image

sorry to post this cause I know the answer is probably super simple, but I have a div with a background image that is being cut off for some reason and i cant figure out, why?

I tried the make the div size bigger with height and width properties, I tried moving the divs around and I also tried the line-height property and I got nothing.

I have been working on this for while so I'm going to work on something else in the meantime I was hoping someone could look over it and help, possibly point me in the right direction.

THANKS!

Here is the HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul id="navUl">
            <li class="navLinks"><a class="taimurknaziri" href="#top"><strong>TAIMUR K NAZIRI</strong></a></li>
        <li class="navLinks">
            <a class="navLinks" href="#projects">Projects</a>
        <!-- START SUB-MENU FOR PROJECTS -->
        <ul class="fallback">
            <li class="navLinks"><a href="#">Websites</a></li>
            <li class="navLinks"><a href="#">API's</a></li>
            <li class="navLinks"><a href="#">Games</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- END SUB-MENU FOR PROJECTS -->
        </li>
            <li class="navLinks"><a class="navLinks" href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="navLinks"><a class="navLinks" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="navLinks"><a class="navLinks" href="#contact">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>
    <br>
    <!-- BACKGROUND -->
    <div id="backgroundContainer"><br>
        <div id="titleContainer">
            <img id="tkn" src ="images/tkn.png"> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Herre is the CSS:

```
body,html {
border:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 100%;
}


/* BEGIN HOME PAGE STYLING */

/* NAVIGATION BAR */
nav {
   background:#ffffff;
   position: fixed;
   float:left;
   width: 100%;
   opacity: 0.8;
}

nav ul {
   text-align:center;

}

nav ul li {
   float:left;
   display:inline;
}

nav ul li:hover {
   color:#000000;
}

nav ul li a {
   font-size: 11pt;
   font-family: Impact;
   text-decoration: none;
   display:block;
   padding:15px 30px;
   color:#6f6f6f;
}

nav ul li ul {
   position: absolute;
   width:110px;
   background:#ffffff;
}

nav ul li ul li {
   width:110px;
}
nav ul li ul li a {
   display:block;
   padding:15px 10px;
   color:#6f6f6f;
}

li:hover a {
   color:#000000;
}

nav ul li ul.fallback {
   display:none;
}

li:hover ul.fallback {
   display:block;
   color:#000000;
}

#navLinksContainer {
   display: inline-block;

   margin-top: 40px;
   margin-right: ;
   margin-bottom: ;
   margin-left: 25px;
}

/* BEGIN BACKGROUND STYLING */
#backgroundContainer {
   line-height: 40px;
   background-image: url("images/nyc_bg.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: 100%;

   max-height: 100%;

   margin-top: 50px;
}

/* TITLE THAT IS FIRST LOADED ON THE PAGE */
#titleContainer {
   display: inline-block;
}

#tkn {
   margin-left: 350px;
   margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Chris Coyier is pretty good at explaining this stuff. This blog post helped me a lot: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ you don't need to make them full screen, it should work within any container.

Comment: here is the Demo with your posted code..http://jsbin.com/yeyinaku/1 what is missing here; can you tell what you want here?

Comment: @KheemaPandey That is a title image of my name on top of the background image of the div

Comment: Hey @taimurKNaziri, did you try the solution I proposed? I think it should solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
max-height: 100%;
background-size: 100%;
```

to:

```
height: 100%
background-size: cover; /* or background-size: 100% 100%; */
```

for #backgroundContainer.

http://jsfiddle.net/hr9G9/

There are two issues you're facing here. Both background-size and max-height are using percentages in terms of their parent div. Background-size also accepts **two** values - the first being width, and the second being height. If the second height isn't set, it will default to auto, which isn't what you're looking for. Setting both background-size values to 100% while changing the max-height to height solves all of your problems.

Comment: Although your method is correct, it is not supported in IE8. Could you please provide an edit for something that will work in IE8 and lower?

Comment: Good point @MaxBaldwin. Fortunately the other suggestion of background-size is CSS2, therefore it will be supported in legacy browsers.